# How to use @FindBy annotation in Selenium for span text?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, findby

I want to know what can I do to get the "Apple" text in span element with @FindBy annotation.

Thats html code:

```
<span class="ui-cell-data">Apple</span>
```

and I tried something like that:

```
@FindBy(className = "ui-cell-data:Samsung")
WebElement customerName;
```

but it didn't work!

Comment: What is the need to add ':Samsung' at the end of the classname value for findby?

Comment: Additionally, `ui-cell-data` feels like *quite a broad class* and may potentially match other undesired elements as well. Though, you have not shown the markup of the page and it is impossible to tell at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the `HTML` you have shared you may/maynot have been able to get the **Apple** text within the span element with :

```
@FindBy(className = "ui-cell-data")
WebElement customerName;
```

Your code was nearly perfect but the trailing part in the `className` as **`:Samsung`** was unnecessary.

But again, looking at the `class` attribute it is expected that a couple of more **`<span>`** tags will have the same `class`. So to uniquely identify the intended **`WebElement`** we need to refer to a parent node and follow its decendents to reach this particular node.

Finally, with the given `HTML` the following code block will be much cleaner :

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  @FindBy(css = "span.ui-cell-data")
  WebElement customerName;
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  @FindBy(xpath = "//span[@class='ui-cell-data']")
  WebElement customerName;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@FindBys` like a chained element look-up

```
@FindBys({@FindBy(className = "ui-cell-data")})
private WebElement element;
```

Or try using below:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@class = 'ui-cell-data']")
private WebElement element;
```

or

```
@FindBy(css = ".ui-cell-data")
private WebElement element;
```

Hopefully it resolves your issue.

Comment: @meert hey bro! did it work for you? Please let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with xpath stated below

```
 @FindBy(xpath = "//span[@class = 'ui-cell-data']") 
 private WebElement element;
```