# Getting empty value when using "getAttribute()"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, getattribute

I'm trying to get the text "Lior Pelet", but i'm getting empty string

This is the site code:

```
<div class="crm-entity-stream-content-detail"><span>Lior Pelet</span></div>
```

And this is my code:

```
@FindBy(css=".crm-entity-stream-content-detail > span")
public WebElement txtFullName;  //full name 

String sContactName=txtFullName.getAttribute("span");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use @FindBy annotation in Selenium for span text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860816/how-to-use-findby-annotation-in-selenium-for-span-text)

Comment: there is no attribute called span in your html, why would you assume this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch by using `getText()` method instead of using the `getAttribute()` method.
You can do it like:

```
@FindBy(css=".crm-entity-stream-content-detail > span")
public WebElement txtFullName;  //full name 

String sContactName=txtFullName.getText();
```

OR

You can get the desired output by using `getAttribute("value")` .
You can do it like:

```
@FindBy(css=".crm-entity-stream-content-detail > span")
public WebElement txtFullName;  //full name 

String sContactName=txtFullName.getAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
css=".crm-entity-stream-content-detail > span
```

means your "txtFullName" already is a span element, so call getText() method instead.