# Pass value to xpath at runtime

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, page-factory

**Please read the whole Q before disliking or commenting something. I have searched on internet before posting it here.** I'm having the below project structure.

```
pages(package)
    > Homepage.java
test(package)
    > Flipkart.java
```

Inside **Homepage.java** i have declared all the WebElements using **POM Page Factory methods** and created **respective method to click on Electronics link.**

```
@FindBy(xpath = '//input[@title='Electronics']')
private WebElement lnkElectronics;
```

Inside **Fipkart.java** I'm calling the **Electronics click method**.

My doubt over here is the declared WebElement is specifically for Electronics.

**Is there a way i can create a WebElement with type like mentioned below and pass value for %s dynamically from main method?**

```
@FindBy(xpath = '//input[@title='%s']')
private WebElement lnkElectronics;
```

Comment: Not if you wish to use the FindBy annotation, which requires a constant value.  One possible work-around is to instead create a List of WebElements if you can narrow them down to the ones you want, and write a method in your page class to pass a parameter and search for that particular item in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Answer referenced from [Page Object Model in Selenium](http://chercher.tech/java/page-object-model-selenium-webdriver)

You cannot create a FindBy with Variable, FindBy accepts only constants.

In case if you want to achieve that variability then you should write or find the element using normal findElement method

Answer (score 1):

As per the *Test Design Consideration* following [*Page Object Design Pattern*](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern) :

- A *Page Object* is an object-oriented class that serves as an interface to a page of the *Application Under Test*. Your `@Tests` uses the methods of this *Page Object* class whenever they need to interact with the *User Interface* of that page. The benefit is that if the UI changes for the page your `@Tests` themselves don’t needs to be changed. Only the code within the *Page Object* needs to be changed.

  Advantages :

  - Clean separation between test code and page specific code such as locators, methods and layout.
  - A single repository for the operations offered by the page rather than having these services scattered throughout the tests.

Based on these *Page Factory* features you **won't be able** to create any generic *WebElement* for which you can pass value dynamically from `main()` or `@Test` annotated method e.g.

```
@FindBy(xpath = '//input[@title='%s']')
private WebElement lnkElectronics;
```

You can find almost a similar discussion in [Where should I define modal specific code in Selenium Page Object Model pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001569/where-should-i-define-modal-specific-code-in-selenium-page-object-model-pattern/49002231#49002231)

Answer (score 0):

**WorkAround : on page class you can define a method, and can pass the text on the fly from the calling class to click on specific tab**

if you want to click any common text on the page. You can create a method as given below and can pass the text on the fly to click on that specific tab on that page

```
  public void clickTab(String tabText){
       String tabxpath = "//div[contains(text(), '" + tabText + "')]";
       driver.findElement(By.xpath(tabxpath)).click();

   }
```