# How to have a reusable method that find all the webelements using WebElement type parameter in page factory model

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, pageobjects, page-factory

I have an automation framework that is driven using page object model using page factory

```
@FindBy(xpath = "xpathValue")
private WebElement notificationIcon;
```

I want to have an reusable utility to find all the Webelements. For that I traditionally use findElements methods which takes By parameter. How can I achieve the same using page factory?

I know that I can use the below approach, but I do not want to write for all webelements like this.

```
@FindBy(xpath = "xpathValue")
private List<WebElement> notificationIcon;
```

Hence, please find me a solution for this to find all the WebElements using a WebElement type parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The replacement for `findElements()` in *Page Factory* can be either of the following:

- Using *`FindBy`*:

  ```
  @FindBy(xpath = "xpathValue") 
  private List<WebElement> notificationIcon;
  ```
- Using *`how`*:

  ```
  @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "xpathValue") 
  private List<WebElement> notificationIcon;
  ```

Comment: As I said in question, I do not want this approach, Since I have n number of webelements in n pages, It is taking more time to write same webelement two times, one for findElement and one for findElements. Let me if there is any possibility using WebElement parameter.

Comment: @NoNoNo You don't need to write same webelement two times. That why [_Page Factory_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46337213/7429447). You simply need a getter.

Comment: @FindBy(xpath = "xpathValue") private WebElement notificationIcon; I do not understand how we can write a getter for List<WebElement> for this?

Comment: @NoNoNo 1) You can't find all the WebElements withreturn type WebElement. 2) You will need a customized getter as the elements won't be readily available and you need a waiter.