# How can I refactoring button webElement with java selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, refactoring

I try to refectoring a `WebElement` buttom with annotation (`@FindBy`). It's same id in different `PageOject`. How can I factoring this `WebElement` ? (eg. validate, search button, name, birthday input)

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436102/selenium-findby-vs-driver-findelement

Comment: thanks but that don't help me, how can I factorize all imput and search buttom from my app?

Answer (score 1):

You can use @FindBy annotations and make web element private and declare a method to access that private web element.

```
@FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="your x path of element")
private WebElement elementName;

public WebElement elementName(){
     return elementName
    }
```

Comment: how can I use this element in different PageObject ?

Comment: Create instance of that class in which web element is defined and call its public method.

Comment: I need to instance an button Class with a WebDriver in parameter.